# How to display vertical nav-bar with some headers values?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the smaller window nav-bar by default is displaying its menu items

[image]

**It should not display menu item when user enters into the site**

And another issue that I am facing is on the first time when I click
on the nav-bar button  menu items do not get hide  after click on the
second menu-item get hide.

```css
.sidebar .sidebar-nav.navbar-collapse {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-search {
  padding: 15px;
}

.sidebar ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.sidebar ul li a.active {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.sidebar .arrow {
  float: right;
}

.sidebar .fa.arrow:before {
  content: "\f104";
}

.sidebar .active>a>.fa.arrow:before {
  content: "\f107";
}

.sidebar .nav-second-level li,
.sidebar .nav-third-level li {
  border-bottom: none !important;
}

.sidebar .nav-second-level li a {
  padding-left: 37px;
}

.sidebar .nav-third-level li a {
  padding-left: 52px;
}

@media ( min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 51px;
  }
  .navbar-top-links .dropdown-messages,
  .navbar-top-links .dropdown-tasks,
  .navbar-top-links .dropdown-alerts {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-header" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
         class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Headers</a>
    </div>


    <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
      <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">


          <li class="menu-bar-list-item"><a target="_self" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleDemo7" data-parent="#sidenav01" class="collapsed"> Profile <span
           class="caret pull-right"></span>
         </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="toggleDemo7" style="height: 0px;">
              <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-bar-list-item"><a target="_self" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleDemo3" data-parent="#sidenav01" class="collapsed"> Others <span
           class="caret pull-right"></span>
         </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="toggleDemo3" style="height: 0px;">
              <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <li><a href="#">HolyDays Calendar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">suggestions & FeedBack</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bulletin Board</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>

              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

It might be a small mistake, I have worked so hard to resolve this, I am not a web designer but i need to get it done.

Can anyone help me on that to hide menu items of nav bar when user first time opens the site and also nav-bar buttton is not functioning properly on the first time when clicks on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.sidebar .sidebar-nav.navbar-collapse {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-search {
  padding: 15px;
}

.sidebar ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.sidebar ul li a.active {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.sidebar .arrow {
  float: right;
}

.sidebar .fa.arrow:before {
  content: "\f104";
}

.sidebar .active>a>.fa.arrow:before {
  content: "\f107";
}

.sidebar .nav-second-level li,
.sidebar .nav-third-level li {
  border-bottom: none !important;
}

.sidebar .nav-second-level li a {
  padding-left: 37px;
}

.sidebar .nav-third-level li a {
  padding-left: 52px;
}

@media ( min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 51px;
  }
  .navbar-top-links .dropdown-messages,
  .navbar-top-links .dropdown-tasks,
  .navbar-top-links .dropdown-alerts {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-header" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
         class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Headers</a>
    </div>


    <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
      <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse collapse">

        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">


          <li class="menu-bar-list-item"><a target="_self" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleDemo7" data-parent="#sidenav01" class="collapsed"> Profile <span
           class="caret pull-right"></span>
         </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="toggleDemo7" style="height: 0px;">
              <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-bar-list-item"><a target="_self" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleDemo3" data-parent="#sidenav01" class="collapsed"> Others <span
           class="caret pull-right"></span>
         </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="toggleDemo3" style="height: 0px;">
              <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <li><a href="#">HolyDays Calendar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">suggestions & FeedBack</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bulletin Board</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>

              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

PLease see the updated code and it will be resolved via adding `collapse` class in the below mentioned div

```
<div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse collapse">
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add a class 'collapse' in  line `<div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">` as

```
<div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse collapse">
```

it will work